# How to check the length/number of characters of a string inputted by a user in Octave?

Tags: input, octave, string-length

Have seen people ask about length of an input but never relative to Octave.

I would like to test the length of the user's response to an input command. I have already tried this method:

```
x=input('enter a set of numbers')
length(x)
```

This doesn't work. Entering "2345" will give you a length of 1, and entering "abcdefg" gives you an "undefined variable: abcdefg" error.

I have also tried:

```
x="blahblah"
length(x)
```

This gives the proper length, but I'm trying to test the length when x is equal to an input from a user, not predefined text.

For example, If the user inputs 5 numbers or 5 characters, I want the length to to be 5.

This length must also be usable in a vector. For example:

```
vector=[1,2,5,7,length(x),4]
```

How do I test the amount of CHARACTERS (letters or numbers) in the user's response?

Comment: Btw, you should prefer `numel` instead of `length` because the later has the somewhat odd definition to return the first non Singleton dimension

Comment: Type `help input` for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In octav you should write the following:

```
x=input('enter a set of numbers', 's');
```

Add `'s'` to specify that the input is string, or input the string by`""`, for example `"blahblah"`, without any change to your code. The other part of the code should work without any problem.